# I want this code to write in Java8 using Stream, Lambda Expression, Double Colon Operator

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8, java-stream

There is a class say AllOrderItems, and in main method we have few AllOrderItems, I have to check few tags {"AttriuteL", "AttriuteG", "AttriuteR"} are present in any of the order and collect them, I have written it in normal for loop but need to enhance with Java 8 using Stream, Lambda expression and doublecolon

entire code:

```
public class AllOrderItems {

    private String OrderId;
    private String CustomerName;
    private int Quantity;
    private String AttriuteL;
    private String AttriuteG;
    private String AttriuteR;

    public String getAttriuteL() {
        return AttriuteL;
    }

    public void setAttriuteL(String AttriuteL) {
        this.AttriuteL = AttriuteL;
    }

    public String getAttriuteG() {
        return AttriuteG;
    }

    public void setAttriuteG(String AttriuteG) {
        this.AttriuteG = AttriuteG;
    }

    public String getAttriuteR() {
        return AttriuteR;
    }

    public void setAttriuteR(String AttriuteR) {
        this.AttriuteR = AttriuteR;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return OrderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        OrderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return CustomerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        CustomerName = customerName;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        Quantity = quantity;
    }


    public String getTagValue(String instanceCharacterstics){
        if(instanceCharacterstics.equals("AttriuteG"))
            return getAttriuteG();
        else if("AttriuteL".equals(instanceCharacterstics))
            return getAttriuteL();
        else
            return getAttriuteR();
    }
}


import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamPractise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studetnList = setStudentDetails();
        List<AllOrderItems> orderItems = setCustomerOrders();
        List<String> tagList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"AttriuteL", "AttriuteG", "AttriuteR"});

       List<String> orderItemValue = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String tag: tagList){
            for(AllOrderItems orders: orderItems){
               String val= orders.getTagValue(tag);
               if(val != null && !val.isEmpty()){
                   orderItemValue.add(val);
               }
           }
       }

      System.out.println(orderItemValue);
    }


    private static List<AllOrderItems> setCustomerOrders() {
        AllOrderItems c1 = new AllOrderItems();
        AllOrderItems c2 = new AllOrderItems();
        AllOrderItems c3 = new AllOrderItems();


        c1.setOrderId("Ord4521");
        c1.setCustomerName("Ontereo");
        c1.setQuantity(3);

        c2.setOrderId("Ord2134");
        c2.setCustomerName("Rio");
        c2.setQuantity(5);
        c2.setAttriuteG("00100");
        c2.setAttriuteL("");
        c2.setAttriuteR("OF010");

        c3.setOrderId("Ord8475");
        c3.setCustomerName("Jack");
        c3.setQuantity(10);

        List<AllOrderItems> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
        orderItems.add(c1);
        orderItems.add(c2);
        orderItems.add(c3);

        return orderItems;
    }
}
```

Want a list of values where three tags are present or it's also fine if its return true or false saying whether all the three tags are present or not, means there is a possibility saying one tag might be empty in every orderitem or not present at any orderitem, if any tag present with any value except null or blank, then will check the next tag.

Comment: actually your end paragraph is not clear, what do you mean return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your attempt with `Stream`s is related to the original for loops. If you want to implements the loops logic with `Stream`s, you need something like this:

```
List<String> orderItemValue = 
    attributeList.stream()
                 .flatMap(att -> orderItems.stream()
                                           .map(o -> o.getInstanceCharacteristicValue(att)))
                 .filter(val -> val != null && !val.isEmpty())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks,

But can this be done such a way that if any attributes not present it will return False, or it just search one attribute only once,

Means if c1 has attributeL and C2 also have attributeL it will return only c1's attribute and not check again for c2

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve list of all order items by filtering out records that have all 3 attribute values AttributeL , AttributeR and AttributeG orderItems.stream() .filter(orderItem -> !orderItem.getTagValue(“AttributeL”).isEmpty() && !orderItem.getTagValue(“AttributeR”).isEmpty() && !orderItem.getTagValue(“AttributeG”).isEmpty()) .collect(Collectors.toList()) Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use .getAttributeL directly from Main, as this is a sample code, in actual code I have to call getInstanceCharacteristicValue method.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but explain what your code does and how and why it solves the problem of the question.

Comment: @RAJUGORAI updated my answer. Please take a look into it and let me know if it works or not